# EventLogQuery not returning results

Tags: c#, event-log

So i'm trying to find when a computer has been locked out on my college's server, we have 4 different servers which the computers use, however my event log query is returning no results, can anyone tell me where i've gone wrong? I cant figure it out and networks aren't my forte

```
private void QueryActiveLog(string compName)
    {
        string queryString =
            "<QueryList>" +
            "<Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Security\">" +
            "<Select Path=\"Security\">*[System[(Computer='" + compName + "') and (EventID=4771)]]</Select>" +
            "</Query>" +
            "</QueryList>";

        EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, queryString);
        EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

        for (EventRecord eventRecord = logReader.ReadEvent(); null != eventRecord; eventRecord = logReader.ReadEvent())
        {
            //Should Get the description from the eventrecord. 
            string message = eventRecord.FormatDescription();

        }
    }
```